# Material UI Autcomplete | Reset value when selecting an option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the autocomplete from Material UI. I want to be able to reset the input when selecting an option. The `onChange` prop fires when you click an option from the list, but I don't know how to make it so that the input resets. I tried assigning a useState value to the input but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="select-add-on"
    options={addOns}
    getOptionLabel={addOn => addOn.name}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField {...params} label="Type an add-on" variant="outlined" />
    )}
    onChange={(e, val) => console.log(val)} // logs the add on object
/>
```

EDIT: I could make it work like this:

```
const [autocompleteValue, setAutocompleteValue] = useState('');

<Autocomplete
  id="select-add-on"
  options={addOns}
  getOptionLabel={addOn => addOn.name}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Type an add-on" variant="outlined" />
  )}
  inputValue={autocompleteValue}
  onInputChange={(e, val, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'reset') return;
    setAutocompleteValue(val);
  }}
  onChange={(e, val) => {
    console.log(val);
    setAutocompleteValue('');
  }}
/>
```

Now my only problem is that when I reset the input value, it still shows the clear button:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It seems kinda strange that you would clear something directly after the user selects it. That's like me typing this comment, then as soon as I click on "Add Comment" the field clears. Do you want to allow the use to select multiple values? (You store the selected values in some array after they are selected.) If so, why not use the `multiple={true}` option?

Comment: After the user types, and selects something, it adds it to a list below, so I want to clear the field so they can select another thing